# How to get the angular route params values in the url?

Tags: angular

I have Angular route: `/Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId`.

And a URL: `http://server.com/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby`.

How to extract the params and query string together in Angular to something like this: `{chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a case of pulling the info from `ActivatedRoute`

```
params$: Observable<{chapterId: string, sectionId: string, search: string}> = of()

// Inject the ActivatedRoute service into your component
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit() {
// Combine the route parameter and query parameter observables
  this.params$ = combineLatest([
    this.route.paramMap,
    this.route.queryParamMap
  ]).pipe(
    // Use the map operator to transform the observables into an object
    map(([paramMap, queryParamMap]) => ({
      chapterId: paramMap.get('chapterId'),
      sectionId: paramMap.get('sectionId'),
      search: queryParamMap.get('search')
    }))
  );
}
```

Comment: I would use `combineLatestWith` operator because [`combineLatest` is deprecated and will be removed in v8](https://devdocs.io/rxjs/api/operators/combinelatest)